# React-Native: refresh screen after change backend data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest, web

I have an app on react-native and a website on react (backend shared)
After certain actions on the website, the application should react to them and make a request to the api to update its state
Tell me how this can be implemented? Even the names of the tools or a clearer wording will be enough, because my queries on google give me the wrong thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [graphql](https://graphql.org/) basically when data are changed on backend it will immediately rewrite data in the app but you have to use qraphql backend.

Or if you want to stick with Rest API you can use [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/). You can set up this library for checking changes every minute on your server.

Comment: Oh great. It seems this is exactly what I needed
Thanks!

Comment: Hey @AlekseyAbdulin. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as such

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket (for example: socket.io) to do it realtime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).